# Cant pass value to controller with ng-model or format date in input tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to format the date in my input tag and pass the date selected to the controller. Here is my code so far:

```
<input ng-if="shutDown" type="date" ng-model="dates" >
       <button ng-if="shutDown" class="btn-xs btn btn-blue-dark" ng-click="assignDate(dates)">Lagre</button>
 </input>
```

I want my date format to be: `ddMMyyyy` and i have tried several approaches. [This](http://html5pattern.com/Dates) solution did not help. This is the approach provided by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

```
    <input type="date" required pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}
">
```

When console logging the agurment passed from the method, it return undefined.

UPDATE:

I have solved the issue regarding passing the date to the controller. Is there any way i can format the selected date in the tag with placeholder?

Comment: format the date **in** my input tag. How? Can you show me?

Comment: it's [impossible to format it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/8495123) inside the `<input>` tag. Buy you can parse it with something like ui-boostrap Dateparser if its `type="text"`

Answer (score 0):

Somethink like this ? get your model and format when print your value :

```
</head>
<body ng-app="dateInputExample">

  <script>
   angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
     .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.example = {
         value: new Date(2013, 9, 22)
       };
     }]);
</script>

<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
   <label for="exampleInput">Pick a date:</label>
   <input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
 required />
<br />
    <tt>value = {{example.value | date: "dd-MM-yyyy"}}</tt><br/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```